# With the imminent release of Windows 7 next week should I wait on getting a netbook

Tags: windows-7, netbook

We intend to purchase a netbook for my mother-in-law's birthday at the end of the month and don't want to spend much more than $300. Information seems rather sparse as to what netbooks will be available next week with Windows 7 Start Edition. Are netbook lines going to be refreshed with the new OS as quickly as the desktop and laptop lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There's no point in reinstalling the OS or requesting the upgrade CD and then installing it. However if you think she'd be happy with one of the Android or Linux based ones (which are normally in the $300 range as opposed to Windows) then you don't need to wait for those.

Answer (score 0):

You can order a dell now and they'll hold it so they can do a "factory upgrade" and ship it with windows 7.

Comment: Unfortunately, that offer only appears to be available for their non-netbook lines. :( Spoke with a Dell rep who said their current line of netbooks won't be refreshed with Win7.